# Ionic tabs will not go to next page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ionic-framework

I have a ionic app project with tabs on the bottom and I'm trying to make a new tab to link to a new page that I made and when I do the correct code it does not go to the page after pressing on the newly made tab button ive contact ionic support and they said it looks right but they can't help me further

Heres my ionic tabs code

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

import { FormsPage } from 'forms.page'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'parties',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'forms',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../forms/forms.module#FormsPageModule'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

```html
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab One</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="parties">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Two</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Three</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="forms">
  <ion-icon name="clipboard"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Forms</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

</ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this configuration.

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'parties',
        loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'forms',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../forms/forms.module#FormsPageModule'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1'
  }

];
```

And in all childrens make sure to have this routing:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Tab1Page
  }
];
```

This for every childern page in your tabs.

Comment: so  this has to be on every page that is part of the bottom navigation? const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Tab1Page
  }
];

Comment: Depend on the name of the page. So change the Tab1Page dipending on what page you are

Comment: also I didd this and im getting can not get / when I run it in the serve

Comment: Ive Done this Code and it does not work I get a error when I run the code